# Wrong result string compare jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting wrong string compare result in my ajax function:

```
$("#scan").click(function() {
    id = 1;

    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        data: { reqValue: id },
        url: "http://localhost:8080/test-notifier-web/RestLayer",
        success: function(data){        
            $.trim(data)
            alert(data);
            if ('OK' === data) {
                alert("yes");
            } else {
                alert("no");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Data is returned from my Java servlet response, in fact i get an alert displaying "OK", then it shows me "no". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're calling `$.trim()` but not assigning the result to anything. Try trimming whitespace from the returned string before you compare: `if ('OK' === data.trim())`. It's for this reason that returning a string from an AJAX request isn't a good idea. Look in to using JSON instead

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That's true, now it's ok. Post it so I can accept your answer, maybe you could provide an example with JSON for better practice ;) thank you

Comment: I added an answer for you. Returning JSON would be something you do from your server, so it depends on what server language you use.

Comment: try to return something like `{ code: 200, status: 'success', data: [], message: '' }` and in case of error `{ code: 404, status: 'failure', data: [], message: '' }` try controlling your status by the code and status message to be consistent across the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `$.trim()` but not assigning the result to anything. Try trimming whitespace from the returned string before you compare, like this:

```
$("#scan").click(function() {
    id = 1;

    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        data: { reqValue: id },
        url: "http://localhost:8080/test-notifier-web/RestLayer",
        success: function(data) {      
            if ('OK' === data.trim()) {
                alert("yes");
            } else {
                alert("no");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

It's for this reason that returning a string from an AJAX request isn't a good idea. Look in to returning JSON instead.